# what should i do to get my emails worked in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

The client gets an email when they create an account. but later they don't get any emails during purchasing. I don't want to use extensions.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to magento. Plz login to admin panel and check at sales emails.

Comment: ok. in the sales section i couldn't find email section.

Comment: i understand. i think you are seeing at main menu after logged in to admin right?

Comment: yes. that's it.

Comment: ok. not from that. please goto system>configuration> sales section

Comment: i reached there.

Comment: there you can see order email copy to option

Comment: "Send Order Email Copy To:" in the order section

Comment: Exactly Anu that one

Comment: what should i change there?

Comment: no need to change anything. you should enter the client email there. Then he/she can receive the mail when the customer made any order.

Comment: bt Teja, is it possible to enter client mail id each time by the admin?

Comment: Anu, why we will add everytime? we can enter the email only one time. when you save that that will be there forever right?

Comment: just enter the mail id and save configuration

Comment: bt Teja, it is only for a particular user na? for every users what should i do?

Comment: Nono, if user a made order, admin email(this one) receives order copy, when user Z made also, he will get the copy. straightly for all users. actually this place is belongs to admin only. if you place your mail id(for ex) you will receive the all order copies.

Comment: ok. i saved it.

Comment: have you tried ?

Comment: yes i did. bt the user has to place new order na?only by then the specified email id get the mail .right?

Comment: oops,it's not worked:(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49279/discussion-on-question-by-anu-what-should-i-do-to-get-my-emails-worked-in-magent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, Apache and PHP, then fallow the below 2 posts.

1. http://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/#comments
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04

After that, setup email addresses on admin panel.

1. Stores -> Configuration -> Store Email Addresses(Under general tab.)
2. Stores -> Configuration -> Contacts(Under general tab.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. bt what if i'm using windows?

Comment: Setup the SMTP Server on your windows server.

Comment: how can i do this? sorry for these questions , i'm really new to magento. and  what about the cron setup?

Comment: So which server you are using? is it windows 2012 or 2008?

Comment: i think windows 2012

Comment: Fallow this link to setup smtp server http://www.vsysad.com/2014/09/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2012/

Comment: For cron jobs you need to create bat files. https://magecomp.com/blog/set-up-magento-2-cron-in-xampp-windows/

Comment: ok.i will check it.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: there is cron.php file in my project.

Comment: should i need to make any changes on them?

Comment: Don't change the cron.php file. Just include those files into your bat file and schedule the task.

Comment: should i need to change anything in the admin side?